# Manipulating of non linear differentials equation

Tags: graphics, differential-equations

I want to manipulate non linear differential equations

> $\dot{x}= x + g\, xy\quad \dot{y}= 1-2x^2-g\, y^2$

where g as parameter.but I don't get any curve on display. Plz help me

Comment: Your question is a bit short.  what is the time range, and the one on g. Must the initial condition be incorporated in the manipulate

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Remove["Global`*"]

{ysol, xsol} = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] + g*x[t]*y[t], 
y'[t] == 1 - 2*x[t]^2 - g*y[t]^2, x[1] == 1, y[1] == 1}, {y, x}, {t, 0, 10}, {g}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Table[{y[g][t] /. ysol, x[g][t] /. xsol}, {g, 0, 1, 
1/4}], {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
PlotLegends -> {"g=1/4", "g=2/4", "g=4/4", "g=4/4"}] // Quiet
```

[image]

For certain values ​​of g `ParametricNDSolve` gives a warning messages,because system is stiff(solution is singular).This can be a help in some cases by changing the [method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html#)

```
 g=3.5
 y[g][t] /. ysol
```

[image]

This may be the reason that the `ParametricPlot` does not shows parametric curve.

**Edited:**

Code for g-parameter manipulation.

```
{ysol, xsol} = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] + g*x[t]*y[t], 
y'[t] == 1 - 2*x[t]^2 - g*y[t]^2, x[1] == 1, y[1] == 1}, {y, 
x}, {t, 0, 10}, {g}];

Manipulate[ParametricPlot[
Evaluate[{y[g][t] /. ysol, x[g][t] /. xsol}], {t, 0, 2}, 
PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
PlotLegends -> {"g"}], {{g, 0, "g parameter"}, -1, 1, 1/4}]
```

[image]